# Another mixed mean inequality

Tags: inequalities

Let $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $\ldots,$ $a_n$ be positive real numbers. Prove that
$$\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2+\left( \frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\right)^2+\cdots +\left(\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n}{n}\right)^2}{n}} \le \frac{a_1+\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2}{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots +a_n^2}{n}}}{n}.$$

I have proved this inequality for $n=2$ and $n=3.$ But I still cannot prove it for the general case. Can somone help me?

Comment: I came across a monthly article by a graduate student, which has a strong resemblance to the one you ask. but I cannot remember which one.

Comment: You'll probably have more luck at the art of problem solving forums http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/index.php

Comment: I like the question and am tempted to have a go -- but no time right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mixed mean inequalities have been studied quite a bit, inspired mostly by the inequalities of [Carleman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality) and [Hardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality), starting probably from [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589560) article of K. Kedlaya. Note that the following holds if $r < s$ (in your case $r=1, s=2$):
$$\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(M_k^{[r]}(\mathbf a)\right) ^s\right)^{1/s}\leq \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(M_k^{[s]}(\mathbf a)\right) ^r \right)^{1/r}$$
Where $\mathbf a$ denotes a sequence of real numbers, and $M_k^{[r]}$ denotes the $r$-th [power mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_mean) of the first $k$ variables. You can find a proof of the general form in "Survey on classical inequalities" by T.M. Rassias (page 32, it is the original proof of B. Mond and J. Pecaric which was later extended to matrices and linear operators).